# Target nth-child(even) of image not working

Tags: css-selectors, swiper.js

I'm trying to make every other slide of swiper js to have a different height.
However when I try the following nothing occurs. Tried several other selectors but it's not working.

```
.swiper-home-image:nth-child(even) > img {
    height: 53vh;
max-height: 53vh;
}
```

head:

```
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>js-beta</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
<meta content="Webflow" name="generator" />
<link href="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f30f6f5e806c6393b4b6928/css/js-beta.webflow.8e7ae5965.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ["Montserrat:100,100italic,200,200italic,300,300italic,400,400italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,900,900italic"]
    }
  });
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  ! function(o, c) {
    var n = c.documentElement,
      t = " w-mod-";
    n.className += t + "js", ("ontouchstart" in o || o.DocumentTouch && c instanceof DocumentTouch) && (n.className += t + "touch")
  }(window, document);
</script>
<link href="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/img/webclip.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<!-- swiper 6 CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">


<style>
  .swiper-container {
    margin-left: 65px;
  }

  .swiper-home-image:nth-child(even)>img {
    height: 53vh;
    max-height: 53vh;
  }

  .swiper-container .swiper-slide {
    width: auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .swiper-button-next {
    display: none;
  }

  .swiper-button-prev {
    display: none;
  }

  .swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-scrollbar {
    width: 20%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 12px;
    bottom: 5vh;
  }
</style>
```

body:

```
  <body>
<nav class="navigation-section">
  <div class="main-navigation"><a href="#" class="navlink first">Architecture<br/></a><a href="#" class="navlink">Films<br/></a><a href="#" class="navlink">Graphic Design<br/></a><a href="/photography" class="navlink">Photography<br/></a></div>
  <div class="sub-navigation"><a href="/studies" class="navlink sublink">Studies</a></div>
</nav>
<div class="swiper-container w-dyn-list">
  <div role="list" class="swiper-wrapper w-dyn-items">
    <div role="listitem" class="swiper-slide w-dyn-item"><a href="/projects/nomad-music-video" class="project-link-block w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed.jpg" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, (max-width: 1279px) 94vw, (max-width: 1439px) 95vw, (max-width: 1919px) 96vw, 98vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed-p-1600.jpeg 1600w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed-p-2000.jpeg 2000w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed-p-2600.jpeg 2600w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed-p-3200.jpeg 3200w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed.jpg 3999w" class="swiper-home-image"/></a></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="swiper-slide w-dyn-item"><a href="/projects/huelga-photojournalism" class="project-link-block w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d8f37505a52dcc9c7d4_Huelga_02_compressed.jpg" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, (max-width: 1279px) 94vw, (max-width: 1439px) 95vw, (max-width: 1919px) 96vw, 98vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d8f37505a52dcc9c7d4_Huelga_02_compressed-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d8f37505a52dcc9c7d4_Huelga_02_compressed-p-1600.jpeg 1600w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d8f37505a52dcc9c7d4_Huelga_02_compressed.jpg 1998w" class="swiper-home-image"/></a></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="swiper-slide w-dyn-item"><a href="/projects/waterfront-street-photography" class="project-link-block w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed.jpg" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 991px) 100vw, (max-width: 1279px) 94vw, (max-width: 1439px) 95vw, (max-width: 1919px) 96vw, 98vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed-p-1600.jpeg 1600w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed.jpg 1999w" class="swiper-home-image"/></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collection-list-wrapper-3 w-dyn-list">
  <div role="list" class="collection-list-3 w-dyn-items">
    <div role="listitem" class="w-dyn-item"><a href="/projects/nomad-music-video" class="w-inline-block"><img loading="lazy" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed.jpg" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 93vw, (max-width: 767px) 96vw, (max-width: 991px) 91vw, 100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed-p-1600.jpeg 1600w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed-p-2000.jpeg 2000w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed-p-2600.jpeg 2600w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed-p-3200.jpeg 3200w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d33afae98092becb1c2_Nomad_01_compressed.jpg 3999w" class="image-3"/></a></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="w-dyn-item"><a href="/projects/huelga-photojournalism" class="w-inline-block"><img loading="lazy" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d8f37505a52dcc9c7d4_Huelga_02_compressed.jpg" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 93vw, (max-width: 767px) 96vw, (max-width: 991px) 91vw, 100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d8f37505a52dcc9c7d4_Huelga_02_compressed-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d8f37505a52dcc9c7d4_Huelga_02_compressed-p-1600.jpeg 1600w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2d8f37505a52dcc9c7d4_Huelga_02_compressed.jpg 1998w" class="image-3"/></a></div>
    <div role="listitem" class="w-dyn-item"><a href="/projects/waterfront-street-photography" class="w-inline-block"><img loading="lazy" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed.jpg" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 93vw, (max-width: 767px) 96vw, (max-width: 991px) 91vw, 100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed-p-1600.jpeg 1600w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3165920c8f20870ae626d0/5f3e2da2f598cb9aab207dd8_Waterfront_05_compressed.jpg 1999w" class="image-3"/></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-container"><a href="/information" class="navlink sublink">Information</a></div>
<script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=5f30f6f5e806c6393b4b6928" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f30f6f5e806c6393b4b6928/js/webflow.ea88d70ef.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!-- swiper 6 JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var swiperNodes = "";
  var pagination = '<div class=swiper-pagination></div>';
  var next_prev_buttons = '<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div><div class="swiper-button-next"></div>';
  var scrollbar = '<div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>';
  var swiperNodes = swiperNodes.concat(scrollbar);
  /* loop throw all swipers on the page */
  $('.swiper-container').each(function(index) {
    $(this).append(swiperNodes);
  });

  var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 20,
    freeMode: true,
    loop: false,
    grabCursor: true,
    keyboard: {
      onlyInViewport: true
    },
    mousewheel: true,
    centeredSlides: false,
    // Enable lazy loading
    lazy: false,
    // And if we need scrollbar
    scrollbar: {
      el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    },
    controller: {
      by: 'container',
    },
    breakpoints: {
      0: { /* when window >=0px - webflow mobile landscape/portriat */
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        spaceBetween: 0,
        direction: 'vertical',
      },
      767: { /* when window >= 767px - webflow tablet */
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 0,
        direction: 'horizontal',
      },
      988: { /* when window >= 988px - webflow desktop */
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        direction: 'horizontal',
        spaceBetween: 0,
        slidesOffsetAfter: 65,
      }
    },
  });
  /*  
    $(window).on("resize orientationchange", function(){
      var ww = document.documentElement.clientWidth
      $el = $(Slider.$el);
      if (ww > 960) $el.removeClass("swiper-container-horizontal").addClass("swiper-container-vertical");
      else $el.removeClass("swiper-container-vertical").addClass("swiper-container-horizontal");
      Slider.update();
    });
   */
</script>
```

Live dev environment here: https://js-beta.webflow.io/
So each second image should be less high then they currently are.

Comment: Please add the HTML for this question. In its current form, the question will not help anyone else who may have a similar problem

Comment: The class `swiper-home-image` is assigned to an `img` element and not the parent of the `img`, so your CSS selector is not correct. Try dropping `> img` off the end